Trino, Hive Metastore, MinIo on Docker Compose Failed to create external path s3a:
I am doing a PoC with MinIO, Hive Metastore, and Trino on Docker compose using latest versions of all official images. I can share my /opt/hive/metastore-site.xml and /etc/trino/catalog/hive.properties if needed.
I have set the MinIO bucket accesss to public read/write and I have set the admin tokens of MinIO in both of HMS and Trino.
I am stuck for a week now on this error and I have tried many possibilities, but nothing works.
In /opt/hive/metastore-site.xml
<property>
    <name>hive.security.metastore.authorization.manager</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.StorageBasedAuthorizationProvider</value>
</property>

CLI
[trino@da599e9df13c /]$ trino --catalog hive
trino> create schema utm;
Query 20240426_232050_00000_hjrys failed: Failed to create
 external path s3a://utm/utm.db for database utm. This may 
result in access not being allowed if the StorageBasedAuthorizationProvider 
is enabled: null


Solved, include in metastore-site.xml

    hive.metastore.pre.event.listeners
    org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.AuthorizationPreEventListener


I had the same issues when upgrade from hive metastore 3.3.1 to hive metastores 4.0.1. But success with this setting in metastore-site.xml
and use s3a://dir .
<property>
   <name>hive.metastore.pre.event.listeners</name>
   <name>org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.AuthorizationPreEventListener</name>
</property>
<property>
   <name>hive.security.metastore.authorization.manager</name>
   <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.StorageBasedAuthorizationProvider</value>
</property>

